# Flipping a multidimensional array java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I'm currently working on a Tetris AI, and I as looking for a method to flip a 4 by 4 multidimensional array. I've looked all over, and the most i could find was rotating, which wouldn't work in my case.
From

```
o o o o 

o x x o

o x o o

o x o o
```

to

```
o x o o

o x o o

o x x o

o o o o
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know which dimension you need to flip, but this is one of them... Please note that this method destroys the original array! You didn't make your needs clear.

- You didn't say which dimension needs to be flipped
- You didn't say whether it should be in-place or create a new array

That said, here's one solution

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Integer[][] myArray = {{1, 3, 5, 7},{2,4,6,8},{10,20,30,40},{50,60,70,80}};

    // Before flipping  
    printArray(myArray);
    System.out.println();

    // Flip
    flipInPlace(myArray);

    // After flipping
    printArray(myArray);
}

public static void printArray(Object[][] theArray) {
    for(int i = 0; i < theArray.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < theArray[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(theArray[i][j]);
            System.out.print(",");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

// *** THIS IS THE METHOD YOU CARE ABOUT ***
public static void flipInPlace(Object[][] theArray) {
    for(int i = 0; i < (theArray.length / 2); i++) {
        Object[] temp = theArray[i];
        theArray[i] = theArray[theArray.length - i - 1];
        theArray[theArray.length - i - 1] = temp;
    }
}
```

Produces:

```
1,3,5,7,
2,4,6,8,
10,20,30,40,
50,60,70,80,

50,60,70,80,
10,20,30,40,
2,4,6,8,
1,3,5,7,
```

Comment: +1 But, if you're using OpenGL you can rotate it by 180 and them mirror it using primitives.

Comment: @Igor: there is no way to know what the best solution for his problem is because he hasn't given us enough information about his requirements

Comment: I agree... we have no idea what he's using the array for

Comment: It is 2 dimensional. I'm swapping entire array rows by reference

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what flipping means exactly, but based on your example, the result could be achieved by doing

```
temp = array[0];
array[0] = array[3];
array[3] = temp;
temp = array[1];
array[1] = array[2];
array[2] = temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

you could code something like (pseudocode, I haven't done Java in ages, but you get the idea)

```
function flipGridVertically(gridToFlip){

Array gridToReturn;

//start from the bottom row (gridToFlip.size is the vertical size of the grid)
//size is the horizontal size of the grid.
for (counter=gridToFlip.size-1; counter>0; counter--)
  //start the second loop from the top 
  for (counter2=0;counter2<gridToFlip.size;counter2++)
    gridToReturn[counter2] = gridToFlip[counter];

return gridToReturn;
}
```