# Mirroring a 2D array: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'double[*,*]'"

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an array that takes a 2D array as input, and flips it. For example:

The input:

```
0 1 0
0 2 0
0 3 4
```

The output:

```
0 3 4
0 2 0
0 1 0
```

Attached is the method

```
    static double[,] flipArray(double[,] inputArray) {
        for (int i = 0; i < (inputArray.Length / 2); i++) {
            double temp = inputArray[i,0];
            inputArray[i, 0] = inputArray[inputArray.GetLength(0)-i-1,0];
            inputArray[inputArray.GetLength(0)-i-1,0] = temp;
        }
        return inputArray;
    }
```

The error I receive as a result is this:

[image]

I am effectively taking the first row, and reversing the order of that, and returning the reversed-row array. Perhaps it is my misunderstanding of some basic syntax of C# as I am primarily a Java developer. Thank you!

Second Edit:

```
public static void flipInPlace(Object[][] theArray) {
    for(int i = 0; i < (theArray.length / 2); i++) {
        Object[] temp = theArray[i];
        theArray[i] = theArray[theArray.length - i - 1];
        theArray[theArray.length - i - 1] = temp;
    }
}
```

The method above was adapted from the above Java method from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13279885/1913389).

Comment: It would be much easier to do if you used a jagged array of `double[][]` type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`double[,]` indicates an array, but you only need to store a single value. Make `temp` a simple `double`:

```
static double[,] flipArray(double[,] inputArray) {
    for (int i = 0; i < (inputArray.Length / 2); i++) {
        double temp = inputArray[i,0];
        inputArray[inputArray.Length - i - 1,0] = temp;
    }
    return inputArray;
}
```

But you still have more issues in your code. You'll have to loop through both the rows an the columns. Plus, you'll need to use `GetLength(n)` instead of just `Length`. In the end, it should look a bit like this:

```
static double[,] flipArray(double[,] inputArray) {
    int height = inputArray.GetLength(0);
    int width = inputArray.GetLength(1);
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < height / 2; j++) {
            double temp = inputArray[j, i];
            inputArray[j, i] = inputArray[height - j - 1, i];
            inputArray[height - j - 1,  i] = temp;
        }
    }
    return inputArray;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked. I understand now - so temp was originally a simple `double`, and not an array. `inputArray[i,0]` is simple a `double`.

Comment: Does this actually work, though? I'm trying to see how this doesn't just flip the first column in each row (from the `,0]`) and leave the rest of the columns alone.

Answer (score 0):

To get the described result, I would think you'd want something to the effect of this, grabbing each each sub-array rather than an individual element, and remembering to set the value at inputArray[i] as well as inputArray[inputArray.Length - i - 1]:

```
static double[,] flipArray(double[,] inputArray) {
    for (int i = 0; i < (inputArray.Length / 2); i++) {
        double[] temp = inputArray[i];
        inputArray[i] = inputArray[inputArray.Length - i - 1];
        inputArray[inputArray.Length - i - 1] = temp;
    }
    return inputArray;
}
```

Comment: A two dimensional array is not the same as an array of arrays.